# Flutter Hero Animation not Working as Expected Between Page Transitions

Tags: flutter, android-studio, widget, flutter-animation

I am facing an issue with Flutter's Hero widget when trying to animate between page transitions. I have set up Hero widgets with unique tags on both the source and destination pages, and the source page contains a PageView with multiple cards. However, the animation is not working as expected; there is no smooth transition, and the destination page simply appears without any animation. Here is the most relevant Code of the page:

```
  Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> gruppenTagesplan = {};
  int expandedCardIndex = -1;
  PageController _pageController =
      PageController(initialPage: 0, viewportFraction: 0.75);
  double _currentPage = 0.0;

  Widget buildSession() {
    List<Map<String, String>> tagesplan =
        gruppenTagesplan[_formatDate(widget.dataHolder.data)] ?? [];

    return PageView.builder(
      controller: _pageController,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: tagesplan.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final cardData = tagesplan[index];
        double relativePosition = (index - _currentPage).abs();
        double scale = 0.8 + 0.2 * (1 - relativePosition);
        bool isSelected = relativePosition < 0.5;
        double position = -30 + relativePosition * -20.0;

        return Transform.scale(
          scale: scale,
          child: Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(position, 0.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 4),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    const Spacer(),
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: AnimatedOpacity(
                        opacity: isSelected ? 1.0 : 0.0,
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                        child: Text(
                          "${cardData["start"]}-${cardData["end"]}",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 26,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Spacer(),
                    const Spacer(),
                    const Spacer(),
                    const Spacer(),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 8),
                Hero(
                  tag: 'session_${cardData["start"]}-${cardData["end"]}',
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => _gotoDetailsPage(context, cardData),
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 4.0,
                      color: Color(0xff6d9773),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 400,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                AnimatedOpacity(
                  opacity: isSelected ? 1.0 : 0.0,
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                  child: Text(
                    "More information here...",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _gotoDetailsPage(BuildContext context, Map<String, String> cardData) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute<void>(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Second Page'),
        ),
        body:  Center(
          child: Hero(
            tag: 'session_${cardData["start"]}-${cardData["end"]}',
            child: Card(
              elevation: 4.0,
              color: Color(0xff6d9773),
              child: Container(
                height: 400,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
```

I have already tried ensuring that the Hero tags are unique, and I've checked the widget hierarchy. Despite these efforts, the problem persists. Can anyone help me identify what might be causing this issue or provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve it? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: In the `Hero` widget, the tag must be identical (same) on both screens. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77086710/5451849

Comment: They actually have the same tag. So it has to be something else